Can I safely use the GPIO or opto-IO pin from Basler industrial camera to drive a 64 mW LED?
I've got a Basler aca2440-20gm industrial camera. This camera has configurable GPIO and opto-IO pins.
If it's possible to do so without damaging the camera, I'd like to drive a 20 mA 3.2 V LED with either of the outputs. The camera is powered by Power over Ethernet.
As an mechanical engineer, I appreciate any help in walking me through this.
From the documentation there seems to be a reasonable way to drive a LED using the opto-IO. Image below, from the documentation actually says a LED can be driven.

Is the following interpretation correct?

the opto-IO, if configured as an output, acts as a switch in the external circuit one chooses to connect to it.
the external circuit needs to include a VDC power supply, between 3.3 and 24 V.
the output does not itself provide power to the circuit.

There is a GPIO pin that can be configured as output. To my understanding it provides a 3.3 V voltage and can source 50 mA max. But it does not seem to be good practice to directly power a LED from it. Correct?
From the 'Circuit diagrams' section:

GPIO description:

Is my conclusion correct that neither outputs should be used to power a LED directly? I should use an external VDC power supply and it's probably easiest to simply use the opto-IO as a switch to turn the LED on and off.
Many thanks!

If the GPIO pin can source 50 mA, then a 20 mA load (64 mW, by the way) should not present any problems.  LEDs also do not have the potential for creating damaging transients that a relay or other inductive load might.  Your interpretation of the opto- output is correct on all points.
Edit: as @BenVoigt points out, you will need a current limiting resistor on the 3.3 V output, even if the Vf of the LED “matches” that of the supply.  This could mean running the LED at a lower current (10mA for an indicator LED is plenty these days and 5 mA is probably still acceptably bright) or using the opto- output and a higher supply voltage.
Edit 2: with the new information, I recommend using the opto GPIO to sink the LED current and a 5-12 V source with a suitable current limiting resistor.

May be worth a reminder about a current-limiting device.  Hooking an LED directly to a 3.3V output is quite likely to cause problems.

thanks both, I've added more information on the GPIOs. Now I'm wondering if it is actually capable of sourcing 50 mA, or only capable of sinking it. Do you mind having another look?

Your understanding of the opto output sounds correct. You have the example schematics how to drive a LED.
The GPIO seems to be sink-only for driving loads, the sourcing current is just for a weak pull-up effect, of about 2.2 kohms to 3.3V.
So you would also need a supply voltage and resistor before the GPIO can drive the LED, because the 3.3V pull-up via 2.2 kohms is not enough for your LED.
If you used a different LED, such as a superbright red LED, it might be very bright even when connected directly to GPIO pin.
